# Android Dagger ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to upgrade older version project to support `SDK 33` and getting this error while compile.

```
error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'com.irokotv.dagger.AppComponent' because 'com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.irokotv.logic.dagger.ApiModule
      => element (METHOD): getClient(okhttp3.Interceptor,com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor)
      => type (EXECUTABLE method): (okhttp3.Interceptor,com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor)okhttp3.OkHttpClient
      => type (ERROR parameter type): com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor
  
  If type 'com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor' is on your classpath.
```

I have update
kotlin `1.3.72` to `1.7.10`
dagger `2.27` to `2.48`
tools.build:gradle `4.0.1` to `7.4.2`
gradle-wrapper.properties `6.5` to `7.6`

What I've tried:

In old project chunk library used with version

```
    debugApi "com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.1.0"
    releaseApi "com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library-no-op:1.1.0"
```

I tried to change with `com.github.ChuckerTeam.Chucker` found in one of the solution but it didn't work for me.
latest version of this library is `4.0.0` but I can't upgrade to very latest because it required kotlin `1.8.0` version and this project used viewBinding so I can't upgrade kotlin version to latest.

```
 debugImplementation "com.github.ChuckerTeam.Chucker:library:3.5.2"
 releaseImplementation "com.github.ChuckerTeam.Chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2"
```

Now I'm stuck with the versions. It seems that the problem is somewhere in components or modules connection or gradle version. I need help.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Proguard/R8 Rules:** *If you are using Proguard or R8 for code obfuscation and shrinking, make sure that you have proper rules to keep the necessary classes, including 'com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor,' from being obfuscated or removed.*

**Library Compatibility:** *Ensure that the version of the Chucker library you are using is compatible with the version of Dagger you are using. Check for any compatibility or version conflicts between your project's dependencies.*

**Update Dagger Configuration:**
*If you have an AppModule or ApiModule that provides the 'ChuckerInterceptor,' ensure that you have correctly annotated the method providing this interceptor with **@Provides** or **@Binds**.
Verify that you have included 'com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor' in the list of provided dependencies in your Dagger module.*

Comment: Proguard is missing. I have added proguard for Chunker but still, it's not working.

Comment: @Harshali did u checkout other 2 warnings?, 
Maybe you didn't give proper annotations to your class and method

Comment: Yes, I have checked other 2 warnings also. Only proguard is missing so I have added. and I have updated **dagger** version from `2.27` to `2.48` in migration. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: @Harshali If you are using dagger **2.48** , please check this links [ https://github.com/google/dagger/releases ] & [ https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/ksp ] , it required Kotlin **1.9.0 (or above)** , and I think it won't affect to viewbinding and if it will then rebuild the project

Comment: If I upgrade to 1.9.0 then as per this documentation [ https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding ] I have to initialize binding variable of XML file and need to use this variable to access every view of XML file right? and in project view binding is used so all views of XML is directly used via its id so, Is there any way without changing all files?.

Comment: Yes you can define the Viewbinding in your **build.gradle** file and either if you don't want to use viewbinding in any files then you can also code using **findviewbyId**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Gradle module that contains the `ApiModule` is able to access `ChuckerInterceptor` class.

Check:

- `ApiModule`'s Gradle module has a necessary Gradle dependency to `ChuckerInterceptor`
- `ChuckerInterceptor` has a `public` access modifier.

In the error log you posted, Dagger tells us that it can't access the parameter `ChuckerInterceptor` of `getClient` function in the `ApiModule` class. So probably you are missing a Gradle dependency in that Gradle module.

If you are trying to inject `ChuckerInterceptor` for all build type & flavours (inside the `main` directory for example) then make sure to check all of your build variants and flavours. All of them should be able to access `ChuckerInterceptor` class, whether the real or no-op class.

Comment: Thanks @Mustafa Berkay Mutlu for answer but I've checked ApiModule gradle and it has all necessary depenadancy for `ChuckerInterceptor`. But I think this project is very old and then I've tried to sync and run this project so some of the dependencies don't have latest version to support sdk latest versions and it creates mess.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue,
make sure you are including the dependencies on every module that needs ChuckentInceptor, In my case CoreComponent was providing ChuckerInterceptor and had chucker dependency in its module, but core component was also the dependency on of my every other component in different modules, thus I had to mention chucker dependency on my each module Gradle which were using core component.

Comment: Are you using `com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library` or `com.github.ChuckerTeam.Chucker:library`?

Comment: com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library

but I think it error has more to do with agp 8